# Where and how do widening reference conversions actually proceed?

Tags: java, polymorphism, implicit-conversion

In [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5), it says:

> A conversion from type `Thread` to type `Object` requires no run-time action; `Thread` is a subclass of `Object`, so any reference produced by an expression of type `Thread` is a valid reference value of type `Object`.

I wrote an example as follows:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread();
Object myObject = myThread;
```

From my understanding, a conversion means a type is actually converted to another type. Which argument below is correct:

1.

> Compiler implicitly inserts an up-cast at compile time. At runtime, the cast from `Thread` to `Object` proceeds so both types of the two operands of = operator are `Object` type.

2. 

> Compiler implicitly inserts an identity cast at compile time. At runtime, the cast from `Thread` to `Thread` proceeds, although the types of the two operands of = operator are not the same, they are compatible with each other.

Comment: 2 is closest I think.  Basically nothing occurs.  At compile time and runtime, `Dog` is capable of all the same operations as `Animal` so no conversion is needed, only a type check at compile time (which trivially passes).  At least that's how I think of it.

Comment: `reference variables in Java can hold values of the same type and subtypes.` I believe this is true.  Since sub-types are capable of all the same operations as their super-type, it is trivial for a reference to a super type to hold a sub type.  They're basically the same thing anyway, so there's no really extra work to do at runtime. (Notice this part from the JLS you quoted: `A conversion from type Thread to type Object requires no run-time action`  That's basically all there is to it.)

Comment: Thanks, markspace. I've edited my question, hope that clarifies what I'm confused.

Comment: I think the point is that there *isn't* a cast, because it's not necessary.   A `Thread` *is* an `Object`, just with additional capabilities (which are irrelevant when you want to interact with it as an `Object`

Comment: Thanks Gus, I believe you are right. Does anyone know  where is "IS-A relationship" defined in JLS?

Comment: In  [4.12.2. Variables of Reference Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2), it says "A variable of a class type T can hold [...] a reference to an instance of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T." I think this is what I'm looking for.